# get checkbox state and value from Request.Form collection

Tags: asp.net, request.form

I try to access the posted value from a checkbox and if it is checked or not. I currently have this..

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="form-check-input" id="chk1">


            for (i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(HiddenNumberOfControls.Value); i++)
        {
            chkName = ("chk" + i);
            var ctrl = Request.Form[chkName];

            if (ctrl == "on")
            {

            }

        }
```

I can see if the checkbox is checked or not using this but is it possible to get its value?

Comment: Try using round brackets `Request.Form(chkName)`

Comment: I cannot do that in c#, but vb.net would have worked

Comment: Now try changing `id="chk1"` to `name="chk1"`

Comment: The checkbox is rendered dynamically inside a placeholder so there is no Name property.

Comment: If you have control over the code that renders the checkbox, you'll have to add the name property

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by setting the checkbox value like this `.InputAttributes.Add("value", "myVal");`